# How to convert from conditional statements to OCP (Open Closed Principle) in SOLID?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

I have a code that performs various database checks based on the passed string value. I can solve it with multiple conditional statements(if and else) and I definitely know it's breaking the OCP in Solid principle because it is open to modification. I have thought of ways to approach this but it only complicates the codebase. (Simplicity is key)

What is the best way to do this?

Currently, I have tried creating an interface that the classes implemented but I can't evaluate based on a passed value since it executes all the classes that implement the interface

Example
if there are passed strings such as 'cook', 'bake', 'sleep' and 'fight'.
I don't want to write:
if(action == 'cook') then DO this
or
if(action == 'bake') then DO this
or
if(action == 'sleep') then DO this
or
if(action == 'fight') then DO this

Rather what I did was create an interface

```cs
public interface Iaction{
  public bool Act();
}

//then create various classes that  implemented the interface
public class Sleep: Iaction{

public bool Act(){
.....
  }
}

public class Cook: Iaction{

public bool Act(){
.....
  }
}

public class Bake: Iaction{

public bool Act(){
.....
  }
}

public class Fight: Iaction{

public bool Act(){
.....
  }
}
```

The main issue arises when if the action passed is cook. I want to only execute the cook method.
Iaction.Act(); executes all the classes that implemented the interface.

```
public IHttpActionResult ThingToDo(string action){

if(string.IsnullOrEmpty(action) == false){
bool response = Iaction.Act();
  }
....
....
...
}
```

Is there a way of achieving this with OCP in Solid Principle?

Comment: Please share the code, where you try to execute `Iaction.Act()`.

Comment: You have to inject the desire behavior(cook, bake...) to the clases with Dependency Injection.

Comment: @Fildor 
I have edited the question

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `Act` is not a static method, is it? There should be something like `Iaction localAction = .... ; localAction.Act();`

Comment: @Fildor you cannot instantiate an interface unless it is a list.

Comment: What? You cannot use it like a static class, neither. It is an interface. This code will not compile.

Comment: @Fildor, you're right... then I can instantiate based on the action value passed. Guess, I overlooked that. I can create a factory method that will handle that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to solve that situation replacing Conditional Logic with Strategy pattern.

Search *"Replace Conditional Logic with Strategy"* a Martin Fowler's book and read ["Refactoring to Patterns: Simplification"](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398607&seqNum=2) by Joshua Kerievsky

OCP is guaranteed by the fact that you add strategies and do not change the code (at most, change the factory that determines the strategy to be applied)

uml:
  [image: uml]

Answer (score 2):

Create yourself a factory method that returns the concrete class of the interface based on your parameter. i.e. something like:

```
public static IAction ResolveAction(string actionName)
{
   ///logic here
}
```

Then your implementation code would look something like:

```
IAction actionToExecute = ActionFactory.ResolveAction(actionName);
actionToExecute.Act();
```

To avoid switch or if statements in that function, either:

1. Use reflection to load the appropriate class, that implements IAction, on demand. You'd need to name the classes appropriately to do this via convention.. i.e. "cook" maps to CookAction, etc.
2. Use a dependency injection container that supports named instances, and in your factory method, resolve the class instance from the container by name, where the instance name maps to the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Goal:

1. Act() based on the string:action.
2. Do #1 without violating OCP.

```
public interface Iaction{
  public bool Act(string action);
}

//then create various classes that  implemented the interface
public class Sleep: Iaction{
  public bool Act(string action){
    if(action == 'zzz') {
       //do something 
    } else {
       //do nothing
       ...
```

If you cannot change Act() method, you can create setAction(string action) method and keep the string:action in the inherited classes and Act() based on the string.

The client should be something like below.

```
var listIaction = new ArrayList<Iaction>();

public IHttpActionResult ThingToDo(string action){
   foreach(Iaction obj in listIaction){
      bool response = obj.Act(action);
   }

...

public IHttpActionResult ThingToDo2(string action){
   foreach(Iaction obj in listIaction){
      obj.setAction(action);
      bool response = obj.Act();
   }
...
```